# how to add library search path and framework search path manually in Xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6.1, chartboost

I accidentally deleted my library search path and framework search path from my xCode project. Now my bridging header file is not able to import chart boost header files and xCode is giving me swift compiler error while trying to build the app.
I tried to add absolute path of the framework in framework search path in build settings but nothing changed. 
Can someone guide me through it?

These are are the kind of errors I am getting

```
MY_PROJECT/Bridging-Header.h:21:9: note: in file included from /MY_PROJECT/Bridging-Header.h:21:
import <Chartboost/Chartboost.h>
        ^
/MY_PROJECT/Chartboost.framework/Headers/Chartboost.h:16:42: error: function definition is not allowed here
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, CBFramework) {
                                         ^
/Users/MY_PROJECT/Bridging-Header.h:21:9: note: in file included from /Users/MY_PROJECT/Bridging-Header.h:21:
import <Chartboost/Chartboost.h>
unknown>0: error: failed to import bridging header '/Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/Jumpy Tiles/jumpytiles/jumpytiles/Bridging-Header.h'
```

Comment: Remove reference of chartboost sdk from xcode and then add again to your xcode project. Xcode will automatically create a path in your framework search path or library search path. Now check your project.

Comment: @HariBabu Tried that multiple times. Nothing changed and the error remains the same.